# Configure Stackdriver logging to retry on RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED

Tags: python-3.x, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have google cloud logging in python project and use it's Client + CloudLoggingHandler.

```
from google.cloud.logging import Client
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
```

On Google Cloud Platform I have some project with Stackdriver enabled.

So far I've faced **Log ingestion requests per minute** issue with **RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED** error code. Log message part:

```
2020-03-15 12:44:51 ERROR google.cloud.logging.handlers.transports.background_thread: Failed to submit 1 logs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
    details = "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Log ingestion requests' and limit 'Log ingestion requests per minute' of service 'logging.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:**********'."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"***********","description":"Error received from peer **********","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Log ingestion requests' and limit 'Log ingestion requests per minute' of service 'logging.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:**********'.","grpc_status":8}"
>
```

So in this case this log message will be lost for Stackdriver.

I know that there's a way to increase log ingestion per minute limit on GCP side, but I want to have retries on sending logs to Stackdriver for **RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED** error code cases.

I found that there's some retrying mechanism implemented in **google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2** under the hood, but only for certain error codes:

`["DEADLINE_EXCEEDED", "INTERNAL", "UNAVAILABLE"]`

So my question, is there a way to enable retry on **RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED** error during writing logs to Stackdriver?

Thanks in advance.

google-cloud-logging==1.14.0